# my variable's value is magically turning to 0 on a button click

Tags: android

At first I've thought this was a problem with Parse but then I started to log the value of the variable that im sending to the cloud. And for some reason the value is 0. I have a seeker bar which updates the value of a variable when the bar gets slid around. I had a log statement which showed the value changing so I know there is nothing wrong with my code up until button click.

And then with the click of a button, that variable's value is to get sent to Parse. I've logged the value upon button click and the variable contains a value of 0. I have no idea why this happening. I know that the variable has a value right up until the button is clicked. And then somehow the value is manipulated

```
public class SettingsScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

 ... //////// ommitted code /////

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings_screen);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    isLoggedIn = intent.getBooleanExtra("currentUser", false);


    if (isLoggedIn) {
        userIsLoggedIn();
    } else {

          ... //////// ommitted code /////

     }

    applyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isLoggedIn) {
                mUser.put("WORK", mDesiredWorkTime);
                mUser.put("REST", mDesiredRestTime);
                mUser.put(ACCESSEDSETTINGS, true); //when user clicks apply, ACCESSEDSETTINGS will be true and so the if statement in the method below wont run
                mUser.saveInBackground();



                Log.d(TAG, "putting desired user settings into database");
                Log.d(TAG, "desired work time: " + mDesiredWorkTime);  // SOMETIMES THIS IS ZERO???  
                Log.d(TAG, "desired rest time " + mDesiredRestTime);   // AND SOMETIMES THIS IS ZERO??? 



            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra(LOCALWORK, mDesiredWorkTime);
            intent.putExtra(LOCALREST, mDesiredRestTime);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


 public void userIsLoggedIn() {

    mUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    mObjectId = mUser.getObjectId();
    registeredUserAccessedSettings = mUser.getBoolean(ACCESSEDSETTINGS);

    Log.d(TAG, "Has user accessed settings before? " + registeredUserAccessedSettings);

    if (!registeredUserAccessedSettings) { //this code will run first time user accesses settings with parse

        workFromDatabase = 25;
        restFromDatabase = 5;

        Log.d(TAG, "launched settings with account for first time");

    } else {
        workFromDatabase = mUser.getInt("WORK");
        restFromDatabase = mUser.getInt("REST");

        workText.setText("Current: " + workFromDatabase + " minutes");
        restText.setText("Current: " + restFromDatabase + " minutes");

        Log.d(TAG, "got user settings from database");
        Log.d(TAG, "desired work time: " + workFromDatabase);
        Log.d(TAG, "desired rest time " + restFromDatabase);
    }


    workBar.setMax(MAX_WORK - MIN_WORK);
    workBar.setProgress(workFromDatabase - MIN_WORK);

    workBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            mDesiredWorkTime = MIN_WORK + progress;
            workText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredWorkTime + " minutes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    restBar.setMax(MAX_REST - MIN_REST);
    restBar.setProgress(restFromDatabase - MIN_REST);

    restBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            mDesiredRestTime = MIN_REST + progress;
            restText.setText("Current: " + mDesiredRestTime + " minutes");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

}



}
}
```

EDIT

I have two seeker bars which are updating two different variables. One of these variables will always have a value while the other variable has a value of 0. The value of 0 alternates between each variable everytime I click the button. This is something I've never seen before

EDIT

```
mDesiredWorkTime = workFromDatabase;
mDesiredRestTime = restFromDatabase;
```

placed this right before the if else block and now these variables will always hold a value

Comment: `onProgressChanged()` can be initiated without a user's interaction. Try checking if the user changed the value with `if(fromUser)` which is provided in the listener.

Comment: What are the types of `mDesiredWorkTime` and `mDesiredRestTime`? I'm assuming `int`. Are the values correct in Parse? You are also directly casting to String when logging. Try surrounding with `String.valueOf(mDesiredRestTime)`

Comment: @MichaelGarner I have done what you did and added that if statement however it doesn't do anything. My problem is that one of the variables is being changed to zero. `mDesiredWorkTime` and `mDesiredRestTime` are int values. Values in Parse are correct. However directly casting it to a String shouldn't make the values change to 0. This is a problem that has nothing to do with Parse

Comment: Just for clarification, only the Logs are affected?

Comment: What are the initial values of those vars? Do they start with a zero value? Your code (from what I can see) only changes their value if the seekbar changes.

Comment: Ah I see what I did wrong now. If the seeker bar doesn't change its progress, the `mDesiredWorkTime` / `mDesiredRestTime` variable doesn't hold a value as I assign the value inside the on change listener.

Comment: Edited my question above with my solution. I just couldnt believe I didn't realize my problem. But anyways thank you Michael for your time and help